# scalable image and div with float

Tags: html, css, image, scale

Does anyone know how to adjust the code below to make my bordered div along with the image inside it scale with the screen?  Currently it only scales a little bit and then it will not get any smaller.  When it stops scaling it is still pretty large.  I would like it so people view this on a phone will be able to see the whole image without it getting chopped off.   Any ideas?

```
<body>
<div align="center" style="width: 100%;">
    <div style="float: left; border: 1px solid #999; margin-left: 40px; display: inline-block; width:100%; max-width:308px;">

        <h2>Large Basket</h2>

            <img src="http://www.detroitdrivingrange.com/assets/images/large-basket-golf-balls.png" style="max-width: 100%;"/>

        <h1>Only $7.00</h1>

    </div>

</div>
</body>
```

Comment: I tried your code and it seems to work. Can you post a jsfiddle with the problem?

Comment: You should look into media queries - this article (http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2013/07/22/simple-responsive-images-with-css-background-images/) might be a good starting point.

Answer (score 1):

Max-with is your problem. Change that property to just

```
 width: 100%;
```

on everything you want to scale:

working example:
http://jsfiddle.net/n4xr3kdd/1/

P.S. To get this to look a particular way on your phone that is different then on a normal computer screen I'd recommend learning about media queries. Though this fix should scale your image the way you were asking.